# Is it possible to convert Smarty template to HTML without outputting it to the page?

Tags: php, html, email, smarty, html-email

The `display` method in Smarty converts the Smarty template to HTML, and then outputs that to the page.

Is there any way that I can convert a Smarty template to HTML, and save the contents of such in a variable?

I want to use Smarty to render an email template, but then obviously send that email to a user.

Comment: @AD7six There's other content I have on my page, and I'm already using output buffering to handle `header` redirects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is [a `fetch()` method](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.fetch.tpl) for exactly this purpose. It takes all the same parameters as [the `display()` method](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.display.tpl) and the two are cross-referenced in [the documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/).

Comment: I was just reading the Smarty documentation, and I guess I skimmed over that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can save it into a variable using smarty _compile_source function and output buffering like in

```
function CompileSmartyTemplate(&$smarty,$template) {
$compiled = '';
$smarty->_compile_source('evaluated template', $template, $compiled);
ob_start();
$smarty->_eval('?>' . $compiled);
$compiled = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();    
return $compiled;   
}
```

and then

```
$html = CompileSmartyTemplate($smarty,$template);
```